# Semibold accented characters bug

Tags: css, fonts, character

Based on this picture :
[image]

With the following css:

```
font-family: proxima-nova, helvetica, arial;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 19px;
```

You can see that the accented characters is more bolder than the other. It's only appear on Chrome and Safari on Mac OSX and Internet Explorer 9 (hum really ?). Firefox works like a charm. The font is from Adobe TypeKit where I included all variant and I tested with all character or default character. The page, Drupal 7, PHP and database are in UTF8.

The following css didn't solve the problem :

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I just saw on FF and it looks like the accented look bold too

Comment: could you post the exact string (in the picture) here? or some demo is OK. I've tried it with another accented language and it looks OK, so it may happen only to the language you tested.

Comment: The string is exactly "Qui fait quoi dans le développement de compétences?". But unfortunately I can't give you a demo because I'm working on a private demo server.

I just tested with Open Sans that is the second font I used and I have the same problem in the same condition.

If it was a language bug the problem should be in other browsers no ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the availability of the font-families `proxima-nova` and `helvetica` in my demo, looks like they are missing in my demo so the text looks totally OK (also the text are bolder than what shown in your picture).

Comment: Hum... On Chrome if I set only proxima-nova, I still have the problem but the accented characters is in Proxima-nova. If the set helvetica fall back, the accented characters is in Helvetica but the other are in Proxima Nova. If I set only proxima-nova in Firefox it is becoming crazy and it puts all accents after the character...

Comment: The é’s are apparently from another font. The causes of this cannot be analyzed without access to a testable document that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Here guys: http://loiclambrichts.be/test/ a sample document in similar conditions that reproduces the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with ê and Ê, only in Safari. Turned out to be an issue with copying/pasting from Word - I replaced them with nice clean non-Wordified characters and it fixed the issue. If you copy/pasted from Word, that's the first thing I'd try.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but I came across this same issue. I was able to fix it in Typekit by adjusting my language subsetting for my web fonts. Adding a language that has the missing characters will fix the problem.